# CRC value for a symbol in Module.symvers is zero

Tags: linux, memory, crc, fault

I am novice to the kernel programming and coding drivers. I have made certain changes in an IPMI driver which exports a symbol. The config option `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y` is turned on. But the CRC value in Module.symvers for the particular symbol is `0x00000000` which leads an error while inserting the module.

Could someone please explain where I can look into, to resolve this problem?

I get the following warning while I make the kernel:

```
WARNING: "vMC_alloc_sel_record" [drivers/char/ipmi/vmc.ko] has no CRC!
```

Error while inserting the module:

```
vmc: no symbol version for vMC_alloc_sel_record
vmc: Unknown symbol vMC_alloc_sel_record
```